# Angular 2, which element properties can you bind to?

Tags: javascript, angular, data-binding

I'm trying to bind to `clientWidth` element property, but it errors that `clientWidth` is not property of the element I'm targeting.

Can you bind to any element property? and does it matter if it is read only?

Is this:
`<div [style.width.px]="width">`
As valid as this: 
`<div [clientWidth]="width">`

Comment: 1. no 2. obviously, yes.

Comment: Please add some code, a wider and extended description would be appretiated

Comment: @n00dl3 how does it matter? Can I still one-way bind a read only element property to the view model?

Comment: 1 way binding is model->view , not view->model.... So binding to a read-only property is at best useless, at worst impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth

> intElemClientWidth is an integer corresponding to the clientWidth of element in pixels. clientWidth is read–only.

You can do data binding with any property that is not read-only and to every input of an Angular component (and directives).

You can do event binding with every DOM event (also custom DOM events) and every output of Angular components (and directives)

Comment: is there an elegant way to update the view model when an element's read only property is updated?

Comment: I'd try polling in `ngDoCheck() { checkReadOnlyProperty ... }`